# vb.net to c# conversion for IsDBNull not working

Tags: c#

The following conversion doesn't work.

> Error:"Only assignment, call, increment, decrement & new object can be
>   used as a statement"

```
VB.net
objUser.Email = IIf(IsDBNull(drow("Email")), "", drow("Email"))
C#
objUser.Email == (Information.IsDBNull(drow("Email")) ? "" : drow("Email"));
```

I need it in C#. Any ideas??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C# `=` is asignment operator and `==` is comparison operator

Remove `==` and replace with `=`.

Assuming that `drow` is `DataRow`

```
objUser.Email = (drow.IsNull("Email") ? String.Empty : drow["Email"].ToString());
```

`?:` is ternary operator which always returns a value. In your case that value is being assigned to `objUser.Email`.

Comment: Err: drow (2nd instance) is a variable but is used like a method!

Comment: This is it
objUser.Email = (drow.IsNull("Email") ? String.Empty : drow["Email"].ToString());
Notice the square brackets....

Comment: @AdityaNawandar: Yes. From now on if you need to convert code from C# to VB.Net and back use http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 1):

You have accidentally, used comparison operator instead of assignment operator.

```
objUser.Email == (Information.IsDBNull(drow("Email")) ? "" : drow("Email"));
```

should be, as you are not doing comparision, its an assignment.

```
objUser.Email = (Information.IsDBNull(drow("Email")) ? "" : drow("Email"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using equal operator instead of assignment operator in the C# variant.
Change the `==` to `=` since what you want is assignment.

```
objUser.Email = (Information.IsDBNull(drow("Email")) ? "" : drow("Email"));
```

Comment: If you're using the `IsDBNull` function provided by .NET, you can remove the `Information`. Else you might want to check if your `Information` class is added to your project.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
objUser.Email = (DBNull.Value == drow("Email")) ? "" : drow("Email"));
```

See the [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for DbNull - where you will find examples:

From MSDN

```
private string AddFieldValue(string label, DataRow row, 
                             string fieldName) 
{                                
   if (! DBNull.Value.Equals(row[fieldName])) 
      return (string) row[fieldName] + " ";
   else
      return String.Empty;
}
```